# Eliminar error Trying to get property 'att_file' of non-object

Tags: codeigniter

Tengo un error *'Notice'* al acceder a un dato especifico de un acceso a base datos y al hacer las consultas de ese dato sale:

> Trying to get property 'att_file' of non-object

Pongo una parte del código, En el controlador tengo:

```
$userID = $this->loggedIn;

$this->db->select("listingID", false);
$this->db->from("listings");
$this->db->where("list_uID =$userID");

$rs = $this->db->get();
$rs = $rs->row();
$publi = $rs->listingID;


$this->db->select("att_file", false);
$this->db->from("attachments");
$this->db->where("listID =$publi");
$this->db->order_by("attachID", "DESC");
$this->db->limit($this->LIMIT); 

$rs = $this->db->get();
$rs = $rs->row();
$data['portada'] = $rs->att_file;
```

El caso es que la consulta aparece bien sin ningún problema.

Comment: ¿Es laravel o codeigniter?, ya que la consulta se asemeja al builder de codeigniter y si es laravel, ¿Qué versión es?, si pudiras proporcionar esos datos

Comment: Es Codeigniter. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posiblemente el fallo es la información que obtiene la consulta ya que no obtiene datos, así que cuando acceder a la información y este no tiene nada, se produce el error, para eso tienes que realizar una validación si el atributo existe.

```
$rs = $rs->row();
if (isset($rs->att_file)){
   $data['portada'] = $rs->att_file;
}
```

Fuentes Codeigniter [result-rows](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html?highlight=row#result-rows)

Comment: Es verdad gracias... la variable se ha de definir y que no sea nula